# How to construct a xpath to click on the element with text as Action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

```
<div class="toolbar">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-button menu-button-active" itemid="sdfsgsg.0978" title="Actions" norap="">
               Actions
               <img src="../common/ads.gif">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

`img` is a child tag of td and class attribute value is dynamic.

error Log :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='toolbar']//td[text()='Actions']
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
 os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 52.9.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:processID: 9268, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, specificationLevel: 0, timeouts: {implicit: 0, page load: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 0f4515d3-fad9-4c70-b50a-27f6c9abd249
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@class='toolbar']//td[text()='Actions']}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:424)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at PCS.PCS_TEst.BaseClass.CreateColor(BaseClass.java:100)
```

Comment: Code trials and relevant error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath is:

```
//div[@class='toolbar']//td[text()='Actions']
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you can use the following *xpath*:

```
//td[@class='text-button menu-button-active' and @title='Actions'][normalize-space()='Actions']
```

---

### Update:

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='toolbar']//td[text()='Actions']
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
 os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to locate the element through the locator strategy as  `//div[@class='toolbar']//td[text()='Actions']`.

As per the HTML you have shared you need to induce a *waiter* through *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='text-button menu-button-active' and @title='Actions'][normalize-space()='Actions']"))).click();
```

But your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty **ancient**.

Solution:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: tried this //td[contains(@class,'text-button') and @title='Actions'][normalize-space()='Actions'] .bt did't work

Comment: My answer doesn't contains `contains(@class,'text-button')` and is not a good strategy as per the HTML. Checkout my updated answer and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only "td" element then get it using css like :

```
WebElement actionsElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.toolbar td"));
actionsElement.click();
```

If you want to click on inside image element then use like :

```
WebElement imageElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.toolbar td img"));
imageElement.click();
```

Hope that helps you.

Using xpath : 
For Actions "td" element :

```
//td[@title='Actions']
```

For inside img elemnt :

```
//td[@title='Actions']//img
```

Answer (score 0):

if **img**  is a child element of **td** try this

```
//td[@class="text-button menu-button-active"]//img
```

if **img** is sibiling element of **td** try this

```
//td[@class="text-button menu-button-active"]/following-sibling::img
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are white spaces in the text, you need to clear them using `normalize-space`:

```
//div[@class='toolbar']//td[normalize-space(.)='Actions']
```